# Uncontrolled rendring with react-router-dom 6.14 with useLoaderData and useContext

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-context

I encountered difficulties while updating my app to the new version of react-router-dom (v6.14). It turned out that the update wasn't as straightforward as I had anticipated, especially when it came to using useContext.

I apologize in advance for the length of the upcoming example. Here's a summary of the issue:

To provide context to my router, I wrapped it within a context provider. Then, I passed the context as an argument to the loader component, which  utilizes. Inside , the child components trigger updates to the context upon clicking, causing useLoaderData to re-render and subsequently triggering API calls unnecessarily.

```
//index.tsx
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <SiteProvider>
      <SiteContext.Consumer>{(siteContext) => <RouterProvider router={router(siteContext)} />}</SiteContext.Consumer>
      {/* <RouterProvider router={router} /> */}
    </SiteProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

now i will show the router where the ProductsMain represents the new version of router-dom and the ProductsMain2 is the old method (i will show both):

```
const router = (contextValues: SiteContextType) =>
  createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <App />,
      errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
      children: [
        {
          path: "/products0/:category",
          element: <ProductsMain />,
          loader: (req: any) =>
            loaderGetItemsByCategory(req, contextValue),
        },
        {
          path: "/products/:category",
          element: <ProductsMain2 />,
        },
      ],
    }
  ]);
```

First, i will show the simple usage of ProductsMain2, which is working perfectly, and I will demonstrate how i try to refactor it and upgrade to the new version.

```
const ProductsMain2 = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const {
    user: { language, favorite },
  } = useCustomContext();

  const [products, setProducts] = useState<productFromDb[]>([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  async function getItemsByCategory() {

    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const url = `${urlBE}${location.pathname}`;
      const { data } = await serverAPI(url, favorite, "success");
      setProducts(data);
    } catch (error: any) {
      throw new Error(error);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getItemsByCategory();
  }, [location]);

  const drawProducts = () => {
    return products.map((product: productFromDb) => (
      <ProductCard productData={product} key={product.item_code} language={language} />
    ));
  };

  return (
        <div className="product-main-container">{isLoading ? <SkeletonScreen /> : drawProducts()}</div>
  );
};
```

And now the usage with the new version :

```
const ProductsMain = () => {
  const data: any = useLoaderData();
return (
          <div className="product-main-container">
            <Suspense fallback={<SkeletonScreen />}>
              <Await resolve={data[pageSplit[0].key]}>
                {(products: any) => {
                  return products.data.map((product: productFromDb) => (
                    <ProductCard
                      productData={product}
                      key={product.item_code}
                      language={language}
                    />
                  ));
                }}
              </Await>
            </Suspense>
          </div>
    );
```